# Difference Sink and Mux filter

Tags: directshow

Can someone let me know the differences in DirectShow?

the difference Mux and Demux filter.

the difference Sink and Mux filter.

the difference Source and Splitter filter.

TIA

Answer (score 3):

- A mux filter combines several streams into one stream. For example an audio stream and a video stream into an AV-Stream.
- A demux or splitter filter splits a multiplexed stream into the original streams.
- A source filter inputs media into directshow, so it will be the first filter in the graph.
- A sink filter is the last filter of a chain of filters.